# Alignement and width of matrix delimiters

Tags: nicematrix

I would like to obtain a linear state-space equation with nicely-aligned matrices. A basic solution using `array` is indeed perfectible (see equation (1).

Now, using `nicematrix` (to obtain same-width columns everywhere), I come close to the expected result (see equation (2), compile twice).

Now, to nicely align everything, the last thing to do is to fix the thickness of delimiters, but how to do it? (And, by the way, why is there a space before ``Now'' after equation (2)?)

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}

\begin{document}

I would like to obtain a linear state-space equation with nicely-aligned matrices. A basic solution using array is indeed perfectible:
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \left[\begin{array}{cc}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{array}\right]
      x+\left[\begin{array}{c}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{LC}
      \end{array}\right]
      u\\
      y=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
         1   &0
      \end{array}\right]
      x+\left[\begin{array}{c}
         0
      \end{array}\right] u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
Now, using nicematrix (to obtain same-width columns everywhere), I come close to the expected result (compile twice):
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      x+\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      u\\
      y=\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         1   &0
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      x+\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0
      \end{bNiceMatrix} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}
Now, to nicely align everything, the last thing to do is to fix the thickness of delimiters, but how to do it? (And, by the way, why is there a space before ``Now'' after equation (2)?)
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT: below is what I used, thanks to @F.Pantigny.**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyMatrix}{}
   {\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
   {\end{NiceArrayWithDelims}}

\begin{document}

I would like to obtain a linear state-space equation with nicely-aligned matrices. A basic solution using array is indeed perfectible:
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \left[\begin{array}{cc}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{array}\right]
      x+\left[\begin{array}{c}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{LC}
      \end{array}\right]
      u\\
      y=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
         1   &0
      \end{array}\right]
      x+\left[\begin{array}{c}
         0
      \end{array}\right] u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
Using the \verb=nicematrix= package (to obtain same-width columns everywhere), I come close to the expected result (compile twice):
%
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{MyMatrix}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      u\\
      \parbox{\widthof{$\dot x$}}{$y$}=\begin{MyMatrix}
         1   &0
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0
      \end{MyMatrix} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}%
%
Now, with \verb=\NiceMatrixOptions{delimiters/max-width}=:
%
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\NiceMatrixOptions{delimiters/max-width}
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{MyMatrix}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      u\\
      \parbox{\widthof{$\dot x$}}{$y$}=\begin{MyMatrix}
         1   &0
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0
      \end{MyMatrix} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}%
% 
This is \emph{almost exactly} what I want, even though the difference between brackets still hurts my eyes a little bit (I'm a freak) and it is not \emph{perfectly} aligned (I'm definitely a freak). Well, I'll give it a go for now, I might get used to it.

Note that in the version with \verb=\lgroup= and \verb=\rgoup= instead of brackets -- which allows for perfect alignment --, I find that the delimiters are too noticeable (didn't I told you I was a freak?):
%
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{cc}
         0               &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      x+\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{cc}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      u\\
      \parbox{\widthof{$\dot x$}}{$y$}=\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{cc}
         1   &0\\
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      x+\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{cc}
         0
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space before Now is a missing `\ignorespacesafterend` in the definition of `NiceMatrixBlock` line 6370 could be `\ignorespacesafterend}`  (I guess @F.Pantigny will see your tag shortly:-) (use `%` after `\end{NiceMatrixBlock}` as workaround)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. I will add that `\ignorespacesafterend` in the code of `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` instead of `[` and `]`?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyMatrix}{}
  {\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
  {\end{NiceArrayWithDelims}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{MyMatrix}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{MyMatrix}
      u\\
      y=\begin{MyMatrix}
         1   &0
      \end{MyMatrix}
      x+\begin{MyMatrix}
         0
      \end{MyMatrix} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

---

You can also try to use the key `delimiters/max-width` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\NiceMatrixOptions{delimiters/max-width}
\begin{align}
   \begin{dcases}
      \dot x=
      \begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0              &1\\
         -\dfrac{1}{xyz} &\dfrac{a}{b}
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      x+\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0\\
         \dfrac{1}{a}
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      u\\
      y=\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         1   &0
      \end{bNiceMatrix}
      x+\begin{bNiceMatrix}
         0
      \end{bNiceMatrix} u
   \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Awesome, but I have two additional griefs: 1) is it possible to use an environment that does not need me to specify the number of columns? and 2) is it possible with brackets instead of parentheses?

Comment: I have added a second part to my answer.

Comment: For the first question in your comment, you can write: `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{bNiceMatrix}{}{\left\lgroup\begin{NiceMatrix}}{\end{NiceMatrix}\right\rgroup}`

Comment: The bracket second part (with brackets) is still underwhelming, due to the scaling. I guess `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` are the winners. Note however that the redefinition of `bNiceMatrix` in your comment does lead to weird spacing issues: the elements in single-column matrices are not centered anymore.

Comment: You are right. My redefinition of `{bNiceMatrix}` has a problem. However, I have modified (the first part of) my answer with another programmation without that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hand-made, but it satisfies the requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\templen}

\begin{document}

I would like to obtain a linear state-space equation with 
nicely-aligned matrices. A basic solution using array is 
indeed perfectible:
\[
% local macros to reduce clutter
\settowidth{\templen}{$-\dfrac{1}{xyz}$}
\newcommand{\?}[2]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{w{c}{\templen}@{}}}#2\end{array}%
}
\newcommand{\1}[1]{\scalebox{2}[1]{$#1$}}
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} &= \left[\?{2}{\hphantom{-}0 & 1 \\[0.5ex] -\dfrac{1}{xyz} & \dfrac{a}{b}}\right] 
           + \left[\?{1}{0 \\[0.5ex] \dfrac{1}{LC\vphantom{y}}}\right]u
\\[3ex]
y &= \,\1[\?{2}{1 & 0}\1]\,+\1[\?{1}{0}\1]\,\,u
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
I would like to obtain a linear state-space equation with 
nicely-aligned matrices. A basic solution using array is 
indeed perfectible.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but hand-made is not the way to go (I have plenty of such equations in the document...).